# Number of element comparisons in Merge sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

We are given 2 arrays(G & H) to join using the merge function from Merge sort. The arrays are:

```
G = [3,5,8,9] , H = [1,2,5,7]
```

For better understanding, I'll add the merge function code as well: (Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-merge-sort/)

```
def merge(arr, l, m, r): 
    n1 = m - l + 1
    n2 = r- m 

    # create temp arrays 
    L = [0] * (n1) 
    R = [0] * (n2) 

    # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] 
    for i in range(0 , n1): 
        L[i] = arr[l + i] 

    for j in range(0 , n2): 
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j] 

    # Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r] 
    i = 0     # Initial index of first subarray 
    j = 0     # Initial index of second subarray 
    k = l     # Initial index of merged subarray 

    while i < n1 and j < n2 : 
        if L[i] <= R[j]: 
            arr[k] = L[i] 
            i += 1
        else: 
            arr[k] = R[j] 
            j += 1
        k += 1

    # Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there 
    # are any 
    while i < n1: 
        arr[k] = L[i] 
        i += 1
        k += 1

    # Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there 
    # are any 
    while j < n2: 
        arr[k] = R[j] 
        j += 1
        k += 1
```

Here is my thinking process:

```
Compare 1: 3 VS 1 [1]
Compare 2: 3 VS 2 [1,2]
Compare 3: 3 VS 5 [1,2,3]
Compare 4: 5 VS 5 [1,2,3,5]
Compare 5: 8 VS 5 [1,2,3,5,5]
Compare 6: 8 VS 7 [1,2,3,5,5,7]
```

While loop ends and we copy the elements from 1st array to the final.
So overall, we have 6 comparisons. However, the answer my university provided is 5, don't really know why!

**EDIT:**
When the array elements are equal, we add both of them to the new array and increment the variables pointing to the current locations. Something like this needs to be added to the code:

```
if L[i] == R[j]:
    arr[k] = L[i]
    k += 1 
    arr[k] = R[j]
    i += 1
    j += 1
```

Comment: I guess the answer is indeed 6

Comment: @HusseinJaber I feel the same way, emailed my course head and asked about the question as well, have set up an appointment with her to resolve this, just wanted to make sure that I wasn't overlooking something small and making a fool of myself!

Comment: Write a program that implements the algorithm and also counts the comparisons.

Comment: @RaymondChen I did that and got the answer to be still 6. I met with my professor and was told that when the elements are equal, we move both to the final array and increase the value of the variables pointing to the current elements in the arrays. The idea is pretty good but I had never seen it in implemented code before, was mind blown infront of her.

Comment: The algorithm your professor describes does not match the algorithm you posted. In the algorithm you posted, when the two variables are equal, we move only one to the final array, not both. You were answering the wrong question.